# Update table based on time difference between consecutive rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a table with the following structure

[image]

I would like to update my time duration column with the difference in time_stamp based on the type. I would like my table to look something like this

[image]

Using Postgres version 11. I would like to run my query every few minutes to update my time duration

Comment: [Sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852/) is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `lead()` window function:

```
SELECT id, type, time_stamp,
       lead(time_stamp) OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY time_stamp) - time_stamp
FROM atable
ORDER BY time_stamp;
```

If you want to update the table, you could do it like this:

```
UPDATE atable
SET timeduration = x.td
FROM (SELECT id,
             lead(time_stamp) 
                OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY time_stamp)
                - time_stamp AS td
      FROM atable) AS x
WHERE x.id = atable.id AND x.td IS NOT NULL;
```